# Is it possible to list all versions of a file with the s3fs S3FileSystem python API?

Tags: amazon-s3, minio, python-s3fs

We're building a python abstraction on top of AWS S3 and MinIO, and we're using the [s3fs API](https://s3fs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#s3fs.core.S3FileSystem.info) to transparently talk to either. While both the `boto` and the `minio` APIs allow us to retrieve *all* the versions of a given file (object), we can't find a way to do the same via the s3fs API. The API documentation mentions a `version_aware` argument described as:

> Whether to support bucket versioning...When set to True, filesystem
> instances will use the S3 ListObjectVersions API call to list
> directory contents, which requires listing all historical object
> versions.

However, when we use the `ls` method on a directory that contains one object with three versions, we only get back the *latest* version - while the minio API would return all of them.

```
from s3fs import S3FileSystem

client = S3FileSystem(
    key="...",
    secret="...",
    endpoint_url="https://minio-dev.xxx.com",
    use_ssl=False,
    version_aware=True
)

objects = client.ls("gabe-tests-1/mher", detail=True)

print(f"Retrieved {len(objects)} objects")

for o in objects:
    print(f"   {objects}")
```

Is there anything we've overlooked?